# How to terminate the capture

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this 
`__data__transition_fadeIn_phase1____transition_fadeOut_phase1__`
and I want to capture fadeIn_phase1 and fadeOut_phase1

I had many attempts, including `/transition_(\w+)__(?:$|(?:__trans\w*))/g` but it only captures `fadeIn_phase1____transition_fadeOut_phase1__`

Is there a way to capture both?

I realise I have to use  while loop like...

```
        while (matches = pattern.exec(Object.keys(selection).join(""))) {
            keys.push(matches[1])
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [**non-greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy) match here.

```
/transition_(\w+?)__/g
```

Example:

```
var str = '__data__transition_fadeIn_phase1____transition_fadeOut_phase1__'
var re  = /transition_(\w+?)__/g, 
keys = [];

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  keys.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(keys) //=> [ 'fadeIn_phase1', 'fadeOut_phase1' ]
```

Comment: Solved! I was wondering about all this avarice and sloth... now I know.

Comment: Yep, I had both of those patterns without the `?)` Thanks again.